# Different parameter while overriding method in inherited class in java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

In the interface I have an abstract method

```
Server launchInstance(
           Instance instance, 
           String name, 
           Set<String> network,  
           String userData) 
     throws Exception;
```

Now in my class that implements the previous interface, I am overriding this method but I do not need all the parameters because that will cause a lot of unnecessary tasks. In my implemented class I want to do something like-

```
@override    
Server launchInstance(Instance instance, String name) throws Exception;
```

How can I remove some unnecessary parameters in my implemented(from Interface) class while overriding?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with Java.

An interface defines method that all implementing classes must support, in order to have a *unifying* API.
One purpose is to be able to *exchange* implementations.

I see a couple of options:

- Add a second method to the interface with fewer parameters.
  But this requires, of course, that all implementations support this.
  This may therefore not be viable for you.
- Implement an additional second interface, which defines the method with two parameters.

  ```
  if (x instanceof Server2)
      // short-cut: do not need to compute network and userData
      ((Server2) x).launchInstance(instance, name)
  else {
      Set<String> network = …;
      x.launchInstance(instance, name, network, userData)
  }
  ```
- Simply ignore the additional parameters.
- If you desperately need a unified interface and want to avoid computation costs of the additional arguments, wrap the optional arguments of type `T` using lazy evaluation (e.g. in a `Callable<T>`). If you do not need the values, simply never call the Callable.

Comment: Thanks. Is it ok to create a new method 'launchInstance()' beside the overriding method from the Interface with my parameters so that when an object of that class will call 'launchInstance()' method, my launsInstance() will be called instead of the overriding one?

Comment: That's essentially my first and/or second proposal, just with only a single class instead of an interface. So yes, that is possible. But then I don't see where you actually need an interface in the first place.

Comment: That was helpful :)
I need that interface for lots of other methods which the class need to implement

Answer (score 1):

Interface is a common API for number of classes. By design you *don't want* interface implementations to change API.

However, you can omit unused parameters:

```
@Override
Server launchInstance(Instance instance, String name, Set<String> network,  String userData) throws Exception {
    launch(instance, name);
}

private Server launch(Instance instance, String name) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

or provide `Data` object:

```
class Data {
    private Instance instance;
    private String name;
    private Set<String> network;
    private String userData;
}

@Override
Server launchInstance(Data data) {
    ...
}
```

Also interface(read data transfer) could be simlified using Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 0):

nope, you just can break the compromisse behind the override... you will need to redesign the method signature  for something a little bit more abstract...